# How to generate form back from JSON Schema in form builder

Tags: formio

I am using [Form.io](https://form.io)'s Formbuilder, I have built a form using the Formbuilder's drag and drop functionality and I have saved the generated JSON Schema into my database.
How can I reconstruct the form builder again with the same controls from JSON Schema?

I want to do this so that the user can make any modifications to the created form.

I am looking for how to reinitialize the form builder back from JSON.

JSON was generated from the form builder's `builder.instance.schema`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to to load the form back by passing the json schema to Formio.builder. I was using vanilla javascript. All credits to @randallknutson's [Github reply](https://github.com/formio/formio.js/issues/2323#issuecomment-579303779).

```
//JSON Schema loaded from database
const createdForm = {
display: 'form',
components: [],
...
}

Formio.FormBuilder(document.getElementById('builder'), createdForm, options);
```

Comment: can you do this with just inferring the data? not everyone is gonna send you a schema unfortuantely